# Which Version of TLS is used in Azure Analysis Service Rest APIs

Tags: azure, rest, api, ssl, tls1.2

I am using this [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/list). I would like to know, which TLS version (TLS 1.0 , TLS 1.1 or TLS1.2) is used in this API, How can I found it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and run the test on the domain you want.

Based on the test, the domain supports TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2.

The version which is used depends on what version the client supports.